# How to send a message to my e-mail programmatically

Tags: php, message

I need a little help with sending a message to my e-mail via php. Here's the code I've got so far:

```
 <?php
 $newline = $_GET['message'];

$newline = str_replace("[N]","\n"
,"$newline");
$newline = str_replace("[n]","\n"
,"$newline");
mail($_GET['to'],$_GET[
'subject'],$newline,"From: ".$_GET['from']);
echo "<FONT FACE=\"Verdana\" SIZE=\"2\">".$_GET[
'thanks']."</FONT>";?>
```

I uplaoded this php code to my sever, then use the execute_shell() function to send the message to my e-mail by then defining the various variables. Here's that code:

```
msg_to="linera@low.com";
msg_from="celebraces@gmail.com";
msg_subject="Hey, what's up?";
msg_message="This is a test email :D";
msg_thanks="Your message has been sent :D";

    execute_shell("http://yourserver.com.au/
yourgame/sendmail.php?to="+msg_to+"&from="
   +msg_from+"&subject="+msg_subject+"&
message="+msg_message+"&thanks="+msg_thanks,"");
```

The problem is that, when the message is done, it just shows msg_thanks, which I defined as a variable. I'm new to php and dont know much. All I want to do is to remove this and rather, redirect the user to a particular thank you webpage when the message is done. How do I do this?

Comment: First, you should use `.`, not `+`, to concatenate strings. Secondly, I don't think `execute_shell()` is the right function to use here. Thirdly, why can't you use `mail()` to send the mail like you did in the first script?

Comment: Sorry. I should Have added. I'm doing this in GML. The native programming language for Game maker, so the code may differ, but this actually works for the programming tool I'm using. So the help I need is with the php part sort of, and how to execute the shell.

Comment: Yeah, including code that has nothing to do with the question is usually not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php):

```
header("location:../thankyou.php");
```

Comment: Thanks man. I've been able to do it. and this is the first php code I've ever written. Never been to any classes. Just realised I needed it and did it. Programming is so easy and interesting. Like you work in one language, and the next thing you know, you can easily transpose it to another language. Thanks man.